# How do you check for nested dictionary structure in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to ensure that a dictionary is not nested?

For example

key and value atomic

```
{key1: value1, key2: value2}
```

value is not atomic

```
{key1: {inner_key11: inner_value11}}
```

One way is to check the type, however there seems to be varies of other flavor of dictionary also, eg. defaultdict

Comment: why would you do this? if there are restrictions on the values, check those constraints (e.g.: "must be a number").

Comment: The first question I like to ask in this sort of situation is "why do you want to do this?" The second question is "are you sure?"

Answer (score 3):

> One way is to check the type, however there seems to be varies of other flavor of dictionary also, eg. defaultdict

This is exactly why the idiomatic way to check types is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). Since `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, `isinstance(x, dict)` will be true for a `defaultdict`.

Also, you may want to look at [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) (or `collections`, in 3.2 and earlier) and see if `dict` is really what you want to check for. If you want to catch *any* mappings, even things like a `blist.sorteddict`, you'd check `isinstance(x, collections.abc.Mapping)`. Or, if you want to catch any container at all (including sequences, sets, etc.), `collections.abc.Container`. Or maybe you want `collections.abc.Iterable`. You can read the descriptions and decide which one means "not atomic" for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value inherits from a Mapping class. Defaultdict is a type of dict, and OrderedDict directly inherits from dict.

```
>>> from collections import Mapping

>>> d1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2}
>>> d2 = {key1: {inner_key11: inner_value11}}

>>> print isinstance(d1[key1], Mapping)
False
>>> print isinstance(d2[key1], Mapping)
True
```